# Have A Timer That Counts both Seconds and Milliseconds

Tags: javascript, timer, stopwatch, milliseconds

Hello everyone i have what should be a simple problem. Basically I need a timer that counts both the seconds and milliseconds. I already have constructed a timer which counts down in seconds but ran into some trouble when it came to adding the millisecond function. When I tried to add a second timer and simply place it beside my first one, it interfered with my first timer. I haven't been doing Java script for long so I have no clue what to do next.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body id="body">

        <div id="timer" style="font-family:helvetica; font-size:100px; text-align:center;">24 secs</div>
        <script>
            var count = 24,
                counter = setInterval(timer, 1000),
                running = true;

            function timer() {
                count -= 1;
                if (count <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(counter);
                }
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + " secs";
            }
            window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case 32: // PLAY
                        running ? clearInterval(counter) : counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
                        running = !running;
                        break;
                    case 82: // RESET
                        clearInterval(counter);
                        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 24 + " secs";
                        count = 24;
                        running = false;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm a little new to the coding community @callyalater

Comment: It's all good. I just wanted to let you know before the nasty comments started. Happy coding!

Comment: What milliseconds do you want to display? Milliseconds left? Or should it be `24 secs, 24000 milliseconds`?

Comment: I meant it like this (24 60, 24 59, 24 58, etc) and then (24 01, 23 60, 23 59). I wanted it to loop like that. The first digits being the seconds and the ones following being the milliseconds. Hope this makes it a little more clear. @Brandon

Comment: There are 1000 milliseconds in a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is slightly less trivial than it appears on first glance.

You can't truly display **every** millisecond because the browser can't handle it.

If support for old browsers (say ~pre 2012) isn't an issue I would use something like this:

```js
var count = 24000,
  running = true,
  secondsNode = document.getElementById("seconds"),
  millisecondsNode = document.getElementById("milliseconds"),
  mOld,
  mNew;

function draw() {
  if (count > 0 && running) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    mNew = new Date().getTime();
    count = count - mNew + mOld;
    count = count >= 0 ? count : 0;
    mOld = mNew;
    secondsNode.innerHTML = Math.floor(count / 1000);
    millisecondsNode.innerHTML = count % 1000;
  }
}
mOld = new Date().getTime();
draw();

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32: // PLAY
      if (running) {
        running = false;
      } else {
        running = true;
        mOld = new Date().getTime();
        draw();
      }
      break;
    case 82: // RESET
      count = 24000;
      secondsNode.innerHTML = 24;
      millisecondsNode.innerHTML = 0;
      running = false;
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">

  <p><span id="seconds">24</span> secs and <span id="milliseconds">000</span> milliseconds</p>

</body>
```

The core here is the method `requestAnimationFrame(...);`. Simply put it is a native `JS` method that executes the `function` supplied as a `parameter` once the browser is ready to "draw" a new frame.

Since we don't know how much time has passed since the last execution we need use the **current** `datetime` in relation to the `datetime` of our methods **last execution**.

**On a sidenote:**

Regularly needed `nodes` should be saved to a `variable` instead of being "calculated" each time they are needed. (`secondsNode = document.getElementById(...)` saves resources because the document only hase to be `traversed` **once**.)

[Here some further reading on requestAnimationFrame.](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/index.html)

[And the above code as a Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ee6a7ext/)

Comment: Thank you this code is working, the only problem is the keys i used to play/pause and reset the code no long function. Could this be my fault for just not inserting in the code in properly or something else? @Ivan Modric

Comment: That may be my fault. I'll look into it.

Comment: @ManjotGill I updated the fiddle and the codesnippet :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this to display the current second's millisecond value. I didn't test it extensively so you'll have to make a few modifications. This is on a 10ms interval.

```
var count = 24,
    intervalMs = 10,
    counter = setInterval(timer, intervalMs),
    running = true,
    msRemaining = 1000;

function timer() {
    msRemaining -= intervalMs;
    if (msRemaining <= 0)
    {
        count -= 1;
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
        msRemaining = 1000;
    }

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count + " secs," + msRemaining + " ms";
}
```